# El destructor se invoca al crear el objeto

Tags: c++, constructor, destructor

Tengo una clase Tramo, con constructor y destructor siguientes:

```
Tramo::Tramo(int id, float longitud, float inercia, float continua, int maxPuntuales)
{
    Tramo::m_id = id;
    Tramo::m_longitud = longitud;
    Tramo::m_inercia = inercia;
    Tramo::m_continua = continua;
    Tramo::m_maxPuntuales = maxPuntuales;
    Tramo::m_puntual = new float [maxPuntuales * 2];
    for (int indice=0; indice<maxPuntuales * 2; indice++)
    {
        Tramo::m_puntual [indice * 2 + 0] = 0;
        Tramo::m_puntual [indice * 2 + 1] = 0;
    }
}

Tramo::~Tramo()
{
    std::cout << "PROCEDIENDO A DESTRUIR EL TRAMO " << this->m_id << std::endl;
    delete [] Tramo::m_puntual;
    Tramo::m_puntual = NULL;
}
```

En otro lugar, cuando se ejecuta la última línea de este bucle (cuando se crea cada objeto) ...

```
for (int i=0; i<tramos_viga; i++)
{
    std::cout << std::endl << "DATOS DEL TRAMO " << i+1 << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Longitud: "; std::cin >> longitud;
    inercia = 1;
    std::cout << "Carga continua: "; std::cin >> continua;
    std::cout << "N\243mero de cargas puntuales: "; std::cin >> max_puntuales;
    tramo[i] = Tramo (i, longitud, inercia, continua, max_puntuales);
}
```

... aparece el mensaje que he incluido en el destructor, por lo que pienso que al crear el objeto, de inmediato se está destruyendo. No entiendo este comportamiento.

Gracias de antemano,

---

Después de repasar vuestros comentarios, veo que el problema que tengo es el siguiente: al finalizar una línea de código donde hay una asignación, el elemento de la izquierda se va a mantener y el de la derecha se crea sólo para ser asignado y se va a destruir de inmediato.
Ésto supone que el método siguiente que también incluyo en la clase Tramo:

```
void Tramo::setPuntual (short indice, float carga, float distancia)
{
    Tramo::m_puntual[indice * 2 + 0] = carga;
    Tramo::m_puntual[indice * 2 + 1] = distancia;
}
```

Y que luego uso en este código:

```
for (int p=0; p<max_puntuales; p++)
{
    std::cout << "Carga puntual " << p+1 << ":" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "\tValor: "; std::cin >> puntual;
    std::cout << "\tDistancia al nudo izquierdo del tramo: "; std::cin >> dist_izq;
    tramo[i].setPuntual (p, puntual, dist_izq); //++++++++++AQUÍ ASIGNA LA MISMA CARGA A TODOS LOS TRAMOS
}
```

No sirve, pues el objeto está destruido antes de la llamada al método. Como bien ha visto Pablochaches, ahí es donde me falla la aplicación.

Answer (score 1):

Toma por ejemplo el siguiente código:

```
#include <iostream>

class A {
   public:
    A() {
        std::cout << "\tA()\n";
    }

    A([[maybe_unused]] const A &a) {
        std::cout << "\tA(const A& a)\n";
    }

    A& operator=([[maybe_unused]] const A& a) {
        std::cout << "\toperator=(const A& a)\n";
        return *this;
    }

    ~A() noexcept {
        std::cout << "\t~A()\n";
    }
};

int main() {
    std::cout << "Creando `a`\n\n";
    A a;

    std::cout << "\nCopiando un valor a `a`\n\n";
    a = A();

    std::cout << "\nFin\n";
}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fZFRasMwEET/dYolBdMWegHbKZhALhGHZiOrqUBeCWlVWopz9Kq2E1LcJt4voZk3A7vSuSdpkA4p3WmSJjYKSm0De4XtsxC9FgJU8CUAwMW90TIfnlDdP5w@xwnc5Lm0kaEsYVFzr9a0KEa9E2dgs2nxc69eIsWgmu0WpKXAfXiG81lnXwb4PzUD65RHtn55s2AAZwp@A64VDeMVR0/wyG86TOqPwxrIqg@pHM9UHKcL6QohNDG0qOmyxymz6g9AjYUd7mq6oBVgIa64a1pZp0cgEryjsR7wD4uwHK52g1/rk7MTKX3LV4OHkH4A)

Este da como resultado:

```
Creando `a`

    A()

Copiando un valor a `a`

    A()
    operator=(const A& a)
    ~A()

Fin
    ~A()
```

Que es lo que pasa en esta linea?

```
    a = A();
```

Primero se crea un objeto temporal de tipo `A`, luego ese objeto se copia a la variable `a`, y finalmente el objeto temporal es destruido, así es como dicta el lenguaje que tiene que pasar.

Esto usualmente no es un problema, pero en tu caso si lo es gracias a un mal diseño a la hora de gestionar recursos, ya que en tu caso el `m_puntual` que recién obtuviste es inmediatamente borrado. Como se puede solucionar? Siguiendo la regla de 3/5/0.

#### Siguiendo la regla de 0

Esta dice:

> Las clases que tienen destructores personalizados, constructores de copia/movimiento u operadores de asignación de copia/movimiento deben tratar exclusivamente con la propiedad (que se deriva del Principio de responsabilidad única). Otras clases no deben tener destructores personalizados, constructores de copia/movimiento u operadores de asignación de copia/movimiento.

Básicamente dice que tu no tienes que gestionar tus propios recursos, la clase `Tramo` tiene que hacer solo lo que haga un `Tramo` y nada mas. No debe hacer lo que hace un `Tramo` y gestionar la memoria dinámica para `m_puntual`.

Para quitarle la responsabilidad a la clase de manejar esta memoria, puedes usar punteros inteligentes. O si solo lo usas como un array, puedes usar `std::vector`.

#### Siguiendo la regla de 3

Esta dice:

> Si una clase requiere un destructor definido por el usuario, un constructor de copia definido por el usuario, o un operador de asignación de copia definido por el usuario, casi ciertamente requiere los tres.

Básicamente tendrías que implementar:

```
Tramo(const Tramo& t);
Tramo& operator=(const Tramo& t);
```

Y en estos encargarte de que tus recursos se copien correctamente. En este caso, asignar memoria para el nuevo `m_puntual`, y copiar sus datos.

#### Siguiendo la regla de 5

> Debido a que la presencia de un destructor, un constructor de copia, o un operador de asignación de copia definido por el usuario impide la definición implícita del constructor de movimiento y el operador de asignación de movimiento, cualquier clase para la que la semántica de movimiento es deseable tiene que declarar las cinco funciones miembro

En algunos casos, las copias son operaciones costosas, y si ya no vamos a usar el objeto, es mejor "mover" sus recursos a el objeto nuevo. En el ejemplo que te coloque y en tu código, lo que se destruye es un objeto temporal, y como ya no se va a utilizar, seria mejor que pasáramos sus recursos al nuevo objeto.

Básicamente tendrías que implementar:

```
Tramo(Tramo&& t);
Tramo& operator=(Tramo&& t);
```

Y en estos mover los recursos. En este caso, copiar el `m_puntero` de `t`, y luego dejar el `m_puntero` de `t` como `nullptr`.

---

Puedes ver ejemplos de como se aplican estas reglas [aqui](https://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three).

Comment: ¿De dónde salieron esas reglas que no conocía?

Comment: @Mateo Pues el origen exacto no te lo ubico, habría que googlearlo. Al menos la regla de 3 recuerdo que ya era un concepto que teníamos con C++98. Yo de las 3 reglas recuerdo haberlas conocido en alguna de las charlas de la serie "Back to basics" en cppcon.

Comment: Muy interesante y detallado. Para el uso que le voy a dar a la aplicación podría haberla hecho con programación secuencial y ya estaría utilizándola, pero quería practicar la creación de clases y no he empezado con algo sencillo precisamente. Ya no voy a abandonar, así que tendré que repasar todo lo que me propones. Muchas gracias,

Comment: @José Solo una recomendación al momento de que lo repases para que no se te complique mucho. Sepáralo en temas. Primero, puramente clases, constructores (incluyendo los de copia y movimiento, pero sin entrar en muchos detalles), destructores, etc. Luego, como gestionar correctamente recursos en C++, ósea [RAII](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7Qgd9B1KuMQ). Y si quieres ir un poco mas allá, puedes aprender los detalles de los move semantics y el razonamiento detrás de ellas.

Answer (score 0):

C++ es más complejo de lo que parece. Por eso es un lenguaje de bajo nivel.

La razón radica en la línea:

```
tramo[i] = Tramo(i, longitud, inercia, continua, max_puntuales);
```

En ella pasan muchas cosas, pero a grandes rasgos:

- Se crea una nueva instancia de Tramo.
- Se asigna (copia) dicha instancia a la posición `i` del arreglo.
- La instancia es un `rvalue`. De forma simple, son "objetos de un solo uso". Independientemente de lo que hagas, será destruida luego.
- El arreglo ahora tiene una copia de la instancia.

  tramo[i] = Tramo(i, longitud, inercia, continua, max_puntuales);
  // Inmediatamente la instrucción anterior termina, la instancia se destruye

Por este comportamiento existen otros tipos de constructores ([copia](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_constructor) y [mover](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/move_constructor)) y operadores de asignación. Cada cual tiene su usos y permiten mejorar el rendimiento.

No hay una manera simple de evitar que esto suceda, porque todas las variables llaman al constructor sin parámetros por defecto.

Aunque no lo incluyas, hay una implementación por defecto. Y si decides marcarlo con `delete` obtendrás errores.

Lo que si puedes es usar punteros. De este modo los constructores son llamados cuando es necesario. O un [`vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) también podría servir. Solo que deberías usar `emplace_back` porque `push_back` agrega los elementos copiándolos.

Un par de ejemplos:

```
Tramo* tramo;
tramo = new Tramo(...);

std::vector<Tramo> tramos;
tramos.emplace_back(...);
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Mateo, tendré que revisar en detalle lo que me cuentas, para poder entender la creación y destrucción de objetos. Revisaré rvalue y los vectores, que nunca los he utilizado.